# I am trying to animate a line using two endpoints (x1,y1)(x2,y2) but line.set_data() function doesn't seem to update x and y co-ordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have used .set_data() method/function to update co-ordinate of the line after every frame. x1,y1 values are being updated but they are not being update in the line plot. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(6,6)
ax=plt.axes(xlim=(-10,10), ylim=(-10,10))

l1, = ax.plot([0.0, 1.0],[0.0,5.0], color = 'b', linewidth = 1)

def animate(i):
        x1=np.sin(np.radians((i)+90))
        y1=np.cos(np.radians((i)+90))
        l1.set_data=([0,x1],[0,y1])
        #print (x1,y1)
        return l1,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  frames=360, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `l1.set_data=([0,x1],[0,y1])`. Is that a typo? This should be (notice the removal of the = sign):

`l1.set_data([0,x1],[0,y1])`